# How do I perform cleanup of cancellation/Exceptions on multiple Concurrent Task's with newest context once?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, error-handling, async-await

I am writing a desktop application to control a small XY stage, following the MVP architecture. There is the UI thread that sends `ViewEvent` to the Operation thread that consumes them, and performs the actual control. The Operation thread runs its hardware control logic concurrently as it consumes new events. There is the case of a `ViewEvent.Stop` or a new event that overrides current task such as `ViewEvent.MoveRight` stopping `ViewEvent.MoveLeft` and then beginning execution. I want to be able to cancel tasks, perform `ViewEvent` specific cleanup, and handle faults such as `LostConnectionException` with newest context available from the Operation thread.

I have tried running an `async` loop that reads from a `BlockingCollection<ViewEvent>` and executing `async Task`'s without `await` and utilizing `Task.ContinueWith` to handle cancel/fail cleanup. The business logic of spawning tasks would be performed inside of a Presenter.

```
public async Task HandleEventsBlocking()
{
    foreach (var viewEvent in _viewEventsQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        switch (viewEvent)
        {
            case ViewEvent.Start:
                Presenter.HandleStartAsync(_cts.Token).ContinueWith((task) =>
                {
                    if (task.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        // Clean up and cancel all other tasks.
                        foreach (var innerException in task.Exception.InnerExceptions)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Caught exception: {innerException.Message}");
                        }
                        _cts.Cancel();
                    }
                    else if (task.IsCanceled)
                    {
                        // Clean up.
                        await Presenter.CleanUp();
                    }
                });
                break;
            case ViewEvent.Faulty:
                Presenter.HandleFaultyAsync(_cts.Token).ContinueWith((task) =>
                {
                    if (task.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        // Clean up and cancel all other tasks.
                        foreach (var innerException in task.Exception.InnerExceptions)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Caught exception: {innerException.Message}");
                        }
                        _cts.Cancel();
                    }
                    else if (task.IsCanceled)
                    {
                        // Clean up.
                        await Presenter.CleanUp();
                    }

                });
                break;
            case ViewEvent.Stop:
                _cts.Cancel();
                break;
            case ViewEvent.Reset:
                _cts.Dispose();
                _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                break;
        }
    }
}

public async Task HandleStartAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        await Task.Delay(2000); // Simulated work. Would be passed token.
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    });
}

public async Task HandleFaultyAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        await Task.Delay(2000); // Simulated work that failed. Would be passed token.
        throw new InvalidOperationException("FAILED ON PURPOSE");
    });
}
```

However this approach does not work because every `async Task` will possibly perform duplicate clean up work.

Would adding an additional boolean flag `PerformCleanUp` that runs before the `switch` and uses `Task.WaitAll` on all executing `async Task`'s to exit and then perform cleanup. The flag would be set once by a failing `Task` in the `ContinueWith` and subsequent will skip setting it.

Comment: It seems that the "Operation thread" (`HandleEventsBlocking`) is not a thread but an asynchronous flow (`async` method). It also seems that this method doesn't do any actual work, but only schedules work to be done on the `ThreadPool`. Which makes it puzzling why this method even exists. Scheduling work to the `ThreadPool` could be done directly from the UI thread, without causing any freezing or other adverse side-effects. As an external observer without a deep understanding of your scenario, the whole architecture looks like an exercise to futility to me.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I never written a desktop application before and everything I have done so far are little test application for small ideas. You analysis is correct that the Operations thread does nothing and it's making me question its existence. This is also my first multi threaded application so I'm learning trial and error.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thank you for helping me on my questions. Now that I examine by application more closely I realize I had a lot of over complication. Originally I called all my business logic inside of UI with `async/await` but I wanted a better architecture, which is why I pursued the UI/Operation thread seperation. The code behind `async/await` was working, but unmanageable, but now I see that I should instead abstract it away into objects instead of threads. Thank you for your time and help.